How to position an element in a specific point of a page responsively without losing my mind over media queries
So, I have a little bit of a weird idea. The background image for the landing of my (work in progress) website is a building I made in blender, and my idea is to put a simple div exactly over the door of the building, which will redirect the user from the landing page to the real homepage upon click.
I have two different versions of this background image, that I switch between via media query: a standard (horizontal) version for devices that have a landscape orientation, and an aptly cut (vertical) version for devices that have a portrait orientation. This means that the position of the door is wildly inconsistent between devices.
Now, the issue is that I'm going insane trying to find a solution to position this "door" div with good responsiveness. Any tricks to avoid using a billion media queries? If not, at least what's the smartest way to go about those queries? (Using percentages? Using vh and vw? Using pixels?)
Thanks in advance.

Interesting idea. Do you have an example of the code?

In my landing page I have nothing other than a div inside a div. The first div has the background image, the second is wrapped inside an anchor tag with the route to the homepage.
In my CSS file I have instructions on the height, width, background size, background position and background repeat for the first div (id=landing), with a media query to change background image and background size. I also have a blurred, darkened version of the same image as background image on my body, so that empty spaces on the sides are filled with something without having to stretch the image.

you can use a image map then hide overflow on resize or use a single link in body, grid and margin and sizing could help : example  https://liveweave.com/DHLLxb which might be useless since we have no idea of your code nor the look of your building ....

Please always provide a minimal reproducible example - ideally as a running snippet. Besides, if you get familiar with media queries you definitely don't need "millions" of them - as long as you over-complicate things.

Absolute positioning using percentages usually works really good for situations like this.

The way to do this is by creating an SVG which contains both your image and its clickable areas (implemented as SVG shapes or paths). This ensures that both the image and its clickable areas will stay in sync as the SVG scales, stretches or crops.
Let’s start with the image. For this example, I’ve chosen an image from picsum.photos which contains three doors:

It’s image number 819, and I’ll scale it down to 1000 pixels wide:
http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000
The first step is to define an SVG <image> element to reference this, setting the width and height to match the intrinsic width and height of the image. This image happens to be square, so both width and height are 1000 pixels.
<image width="1000" height="1000" href="http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000"></image>

Then set the SVG viewbox to match.
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image width="1000" height="1000" href="http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000"></image>
</svg>

Then define the clickable areas within this space. We can use any SVG shapes or paths to do this; in this case the doors are simple rectangles, so we can use <rect>. An SVG editing application can help make this step easy, particularly if you are needing more complex shapes for the clickable areas.
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <image width="1000" height="1000" href="http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000"></image>
  <rect x="242" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  <rect x="432" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  <rect x="621" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
</svg>

Finally, we need to wrap each <rect> in an anchor <a> tag, so that we can use it as a link. Usually you would just set the href attribute to specify the link destination, but in this snippet I am using Javascript to trigger an alert box. Run it and tap on each of the three doors.


document.querySelector('.s1').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName=='rect')
    alert(`door ${evt.target.closest('a').dataset.door} opened`)
})
.s1 {
  max-height: 90vh;
}

.s1 a {
  fill: transparent;
}

.s1 a:hover {
  fill: #fff7;
}
<svg class="s1" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <image width="1000" height="1000" href="http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000"></image>
 
  <a data-door="1">
    <rect x="242" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>

  <a data-door="2">
    <rect x="432" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>
  
  <a data-door="3">
    <rect x="621" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>
</svg>



The final step is to make the SVG cover the viewport. With an image, this would be achieved by styling the image with object-fit and object-position, but these don’t work with inline SVG. Similar effects can be achieved using SVG’s preserveAspectRatio attribute; the following value is the equivalent of object-fit: cover combined with object-position: center bottom :
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice"

With a slice of luck you’ll find a value for preserveAspectRatio which will crop your image nicely regardless of the viewport size, meaning you’ll only need a single rendered image instead of two.
Here is a snippet to demonstrate the finished solution. After running it, use the full page link to properly test the responsive behaviour.


document.querySelector('.door').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (evt.target.nodeName=='rect')
    alert(`door ${evt.target.closest('a').dataset.door} opened`)
})
html, body, .door {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.door {
  width: 100%;
}

.door a {
  fill: transparent;
}

.door a:hover {
  fill: #fff7;
}
<svg class="door" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax slice">

  <image width="1000" height="1000" href="http://picsum.photos/id/819/1000"></image>
 
  <a data-door="1">
    <rect x="242" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>

  <a data-door="2">
    <rect x="432" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>
  
  <a data-door="3">
    <rect x="621" y="673" width="133" height="187"/>
  </a>
</svg>



It’s also worth taking the ImageMapper website for a spin; it is a code generator which does the hard work for you with a sweet point-and-click interface.

This is the way to go if you don't want to use javascript, gg

I think you have to use @media unless you use tools like bootstrap or tailwind.
I know there are standards though to make it a little easier.
Mobile: 320-480px
Tablet: 481-768px
Desktop: 769-1024px
Xl Desktop: 1201px and up
I use Tailwind and for this you write inline css like md: lg: xl: instead of pixels
What front end framework are you using?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You could try and build that with a display of grid.
Also there's a kinda new way instead of @media which is @container . you can check this video i think it can be really helpfull.
